# Meteor data-context with iron-router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I am new to Meteor and I'm trying to set the data context in a page that displays one passage.  I need to access the data in passage_item.js Template.passageItem.rendered but no context is set at that point.  I think I need something like  {{#with passage}} but "passage" does not exist in one_passage.html.

Here are some code snippets.  Thanks.

router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('passagesList', {path: '/'});
    this.route('onePassage', { 
    path: '/passages/:_id',
    data: function() { return Passages.findOne(this.params._id); }
    });
});
```

one_passage.html

```
<template name="onePassage">
    {{> passageItem}}
</template>
```

passage-item.html

```
<template name="passageItem">
  <div class="passage">
    <div class="one-passage">
      <h4><a href= "{{pathFor 'onePassage'}}">{{title}}</a></h4>
     <div class="passage-content">
    {{content}}
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

passage_item.js

```
Template.passageItem.helpers({
});

Template.passageItem.rendered = function() {
    Meteor.defer(function() {
    $('.passage-content').lettering('words');
   //I want to be able to access the data object here. I have a list of words that are highlighted
    });
};
```

Comment: What I ended up doing was adding the PassageId to the html.  <div class="one-passage" id="{{_id}}"> then getting it out again in the javascript and using it to grab the data. var passageId = $('.one-passage').attr('id');
 data = Passages.findOne(passageId);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Collection**

Assuming you created your Passages collection like this and you've got autopublish turned on (which it is by default):

```
Passages = new Meteor.Collection('passages');
```

**Router Map**

And you mapped your router like this:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.route('onePassage', { 
        path: '/passages/:_id',
        template: 'passageItem' // <-- to be explicit
        data: function() {
            return Passages.findOne(this.params._id);
        }
    });
});
```

**Template**

And your template looks like the template below:

```
<template name="passageItem">
    <div class="passage">
        <div class="one-passage">
            <h4><a href= "{{pathFor 'onePassage'}}">{{title}}</a></h4>
            <div class="passage-content">
                {{content}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

The scope of 'this' in the template will be set to document returned by the Passages.findOne selector.

If the template doesn't render that means you're either searching for passage that doesn't exist, or your passage is missing title or content fields.

**Rendered Function**

Now for the last part of your question. The scope of 'this' in a rendered function is set to the template instance.  So if you need to access the template data try this:

```
Template.passageItem.rendered = function() {
    console.log(this.data); // you should see your passage object in the console
};
```

Comment: Very helpful! I think I see what is going on.  Template.passageHighlight.rendered = function() {
    console.log('rendered this' + this.data);  //Works as expected
    Meteor.defer(function() {
 console.log('defered this' + this.data); //undefined.

Comment: so what works is to set passageId before the defer. 

Template.passageHighlight.rendered = function() {
    var passageId = this.data._id;
    Meteor.defer(function() {

Comment: You're exactly right!  The scope of 'this' changes inside the Meteor.defer function callback.

Answer (score 2):

As of Meteor 1.0.3.1, the new Iron Router data selector appears to be...

```
Template.TemplateName.rendered = function() {
  console.log(UI.getData());
};
```

Comment: This should be the answer!

Answer (score -1):

I assume a passage consists of {'title':'', 'content':''}

Then this should work:

in router.js

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('passagesList', {path: '/'});
  this.route('onePassage', { 
    path: '/passages/:_id',
    data: {
      passage: function() { return Passages.findOne(this.params._id); }
    }
  });
});
```

in passage-item.html:

```
<template name="passageItem">
{{#each passage}}
  <div class="passage">
    <div class="one-passage">
      <h4><a href= "{{pathFor 'onePassage'}}">{{title}}</a></h4>
        <div class="passage-content">
        {{content}}
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Yes passage has title, content and also wordsHighlighted that I want to use in Template.passageItem.rendered to set background color.  I tried what you suggested and its not working for me.  I thought that naming the data was what I had missed but I tried exactly what you said, and #with and {{> passageItem passage}} and with all of these I get that this is still Window.

Comment: That's not working because in the router map "data" function you use the findOne selector -- which returns an object -- and used an the {{#each}} tag in your template. The {{#each}} tag is expecting a collection cursor or array to iterate through.