# Meteor, Iron-Router check for data?

Tags: meteor

I have the following setup in my Iron Router config:

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('test', {
    path: '/test',
    template: 'test'
  });
  this.route('test_post_pay', {
    path: '/test/:optionalParm?',
    template: 'test',
    data: {
      message: 'thank you for donation'
    } 
  });
});
```

As you can see, they both point to the same template but one supplies a message variable, is there a way to check for this variable in my Meteor code when the page loads? I want to pop a modal up if there is a message being provided by Iron Router

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional statement in your handlebars template.

In this case it would be

```
{{#if message}}
    <div class="modal">{{message}}</div>
{{/if}}
```

Comment: is there a way to do in client-side Meteor/JS?

Comment: ok, the JS way is basically answered here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579907/meteor-data-context-with-iron-router?rq=1

you basically go in the 
Template.test.rendered => this.data will be your object data

Comment: that way will no longer work with the upcoming release of Meteor 0.8.0. I think you could try using an after declaration in your iron-router route.

Comment: rendered only fires once, in this scenario, it would not display the message if you are already on the page