# Accessing iron router data from helper functions

Tags: meteor

Refer to the code below please:

```
Router.route('/posts/:_id', function () {
   this.render('Post', {
     to: 'content',
     data: function () {
       return Posts.findOne({id: this.params._id});
     }
   });
 });
```

If a `Post` object has `title` and `body` fileds in MongoDB, I can access them from `Post.html` template like

```
<h4>Post title: {{title}}</h4>
<h3>Post body: {{body}}</h4>
```

I would like to access `Post` object from `Post.js` in a template helper function. Is it possible?

Update:
According to this question: [Meteor data-context with iron-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579907/meteor-data-context-with-iron-router), I can access the `data` variable like this:

```
 Template.Post.rendered = function() {
    console.log(this.data)
  }
```

Is there a way to do this inside `Template.Post.events` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you are looking for the [Template.currentData()](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_instance) method.

```
Template.example.events({
    'click #test':function(e,t){
      console.log(Template.currentData())
    }
 })
```

**update** Seems like using currentData have differents behaviors depending the case [check this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-talk/PrzfPlYKYjk)

So it seems like if you want to use it, you it should be inside a DOM element.

```
Template.post.events({
  'click h4':function(){
    console.log(Template.currentData()) // and should return the title.
  }
})
```

based on the stubalio says.

> Inside an event handler, returns the data context of the element that
>   fired the event.