# iron-router template data in rendered callback

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router

I'm passing a data object to a template with iron-router but would like to access the data within the `Template.name.rendered = function() { ... }` callback.

From [Meteor data-context with iron-router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21579907/meteor-data-context-with-iron-router) I've tried `UI.getData()` but receive an error `There is no current view`. Using `this.data` returns null.

How can I get access to the data object passed to the template from the rendered callback?

Comment: If you used the [`data`](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/#rendering-templates-with-data) method in your route declaration, it should assign what you return from that function to the data context of the instance of the template you are rendering, and you **should** be able to access it through its [`data`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_data) property. In `onRendered`, [the template instance is stored in `this`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered). So your data *should* be accessed through `this.data`. Make sure you have no error around your data assignment?

Comment: `this.data` should be able to access data-context, share your data context setting code too.

Comment: Thank you for the responses, turns out I just wasn't paying attention to scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right track with looking for the data context, but this is actually how you get access to it:

```
var ctx = Template.currentData();
```

Also, I believe `Template.x.rendered` is about to be deprecated, so if that doesn't work, try using

```
Template.x.onRendered(function() { 
  var ctx = Template.currentData();
  console.log(ctx);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I wasn't accessing the data in the right scope, `Template.currentData()` and `this.data` now work fine. Thanks for the suggestion to switch the `onRendered()`